# difference between where and having with respect to aliases

Tags: sql, group-by, having, having-clause

If I create an alias in the `select` clause then I cannot use it in the `where` clause because according to the order of execution of sql queries `where` comes before `select`.

But I can create an alias in the `select` clause and use it in a `having` clause though `having` comes before `select`.

Why is it so?

Ex:

```
select type, (case when number>25 then 1 else 0 end) inc 
from animals
where inc='1';
```

this wont work. But,

```
select type, (case when number>25 then 1 else 0 end) inc 
from animals
having inc='1';
```

This works. Why so?

Comment: This is a MySQL extension to the standard. You can't reference column aliases in `having` in SQL Server for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically because they where defined for different purposes. The `WHERE` clause is for records filtering and the `HAVING` clause is designed for filtering with **aggregate functions** (`GROUP BY`). 
In your second query an implicit `GROUP BY` filtering is being used, so for instance, if you add another column to the `SELECT` clause you will end up with different results.

**EDIT** based on correction by Martin Smith

`HAVING` was created to allow filtering of rows resulting of a `GROUP BY`. When no `GROUP BY` is specified, the whole result is considered a group.

> If neither a `<where clause>` nor a `<group by clause>` is specified,
>   then let T be the result  of the preceding `<from clause>`

or

> ...the group is the
>            entire table if no `<group by clause>` is specified

**EDIT 2**
Now regarding the ALIAS:

The specification for the WHERE clause regarding the columns references in the search condition says this:

> Each `<column reference>` directly contained in the `<search
>   condition>` shall
>               unambiguously reference **a column** of T or be an outer reference.

*Refer to: 7.6  `<where clause>`, Syntax Rule 1.*

The specification for the HAVING clause regarding the columns references in the search condition says this:

> Each `<column reference>` directly contained in the  `<search
>   condition>` shall             unambiguously reference **a grouping column** of T
>   or be an outer reference.

*Refer to: 7.8  `<having clause>`, Syntax Rule 1.*

And a **grouping column** is defined as:

> A column referenced in a `<group by clause>` is a grouping column.

So in conclusion the `WHERE` must reference a column of the table and the `HAVING` clause must reference a grouping column of the group of rows.

[(Second Informal Review Draft) ISO/IEC 9075:1992, Database
         Language SQL- July 30, 1992](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt)

Comment: But how is it that 'having' picks up the alias even before 'select' is executed?

Comment: Any citation for "In standard SQL you can't use a HAVING clause without a GROUP BY"?

Comment: No citation, but it's well known that HAVING was created for filtering rows resulting of a GROUP BY clause. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL

Comment: @user1619966 HAVING doesn't pick up the alias before the select is executed. Every time you run an SQL query in most databases, the DB engine process your SQL and creates an execution plan, the SQL gets transformed and improved and what you see in your screen is not always exactly what gets executed.

Comment: `SELECT SUM(number) FROM SomeTable` is perfectly valid SQL. Pretty sure `SELECT SUM(number) FROM SomeTable HAVING SUM(number) > 1000` is too and your last line is incorrect. Feel free to point me to [the relevant part of the specification](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) where you believe this is prohibited. All I see is `<table expression> ::= <from clause> [ <where clause> ][ <group by clause> ][ <having clause> ]` indicating any permutation of the three is fine.

Comment: I m sorry but I m still not clear. Let me put it this way.        If we create an alias in the 'select' statement we cannot use it in the 'where' clause. If we want to use it then it should be something like this:                                           select t1.type, t1.inc 
from (select type,(case when number>25 then 1 else 0 end)inc from animals) t1
where t1.inc=1;  But with 'having' we can use it. why so? (My question is more toward using aliases)

Comment: @user1619966 the answer has been improved.

Comment: @davidmontoyago thank you , the last post(EDIT 2 regarding the ALIAS) was really helpful!

Comment: @davidmontoyago Could you please give one more clarification...In the  example mentioned at the very beginning, since there is no 'group by' used with 'having', it considers the whole table as group and thereby it is able to understand the  alias?..Is this a correct line of thought?